# MoveIt blacks RViz screen out

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a problem using MoveIt:

I have a .urdf file I can display in RViz without any problems. I then wanted to use MoveIt and get a black screen in 90% of all cases. It loads the robot in (I can chose the joints, etc) but it only shows me a black screen, not even the grid. When I go into my launch/move_group.launch file and comment out the move_group note

```
     <node name="move_group" launch-prefix="$(arg launch_prefix)" pkg="moveit_ros_move_group" type="move_group" respawn="false" output="screen" args="$(arg command_args)">
...
...
...
</node>
```

it works perfectly fine for me. If I use the commented code and turn on the debugger, it throws me the following error:

```
    Starting program: /opt/ros/groovy/lib/moveit_ros_move_group/move_group --debug __name:=move_group __log:=/home/ajm/.ros/log/b889376e-09b1-11e3-8f77-c417fe8535ce/move_group-4.log
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
process[rviz_ajm_Latitude_E6500_24301_566916859287898865-5]: started with pid [24365]
```

I was already tried the following:

- disable/enable MoveIt in RViz
- try different ogre-rtt settings
- reinstall MoveIt (normal and developer version)

Any input is well appreciated. I also welcome more information regarding tcsetpgrp.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/74050/moveit-blacks-rviz-screen-out/) by [Talatos](https://answers.ros.org/users/6064/talatos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This can be for the graphics card. I changed my computer and resolved the problem.
[Here](http://answers.ros.org/question/49072/rviz-black-screen/), had the same problem.

---

Originally posted by [alex.filgueira](https://answers.ros.org/users/11401/alex.filgueira/) with karma: 62 on 2014-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on 2014-03-06**:
This is more likely the correct answer. I dont think it has anything to do with RAM. Once the correct driver is used, there should be no issue. Else there is be cases in which rviz is also blacked out